# ¿Como puedo mostrar un Log personalizado?

Tags: java, android

Hola necesito mostrar un Log personalizado, para ver lo que sucede en mi aplicación en tiempo real aquí la función Log:

```
 protected void Log(){
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            log.append(line);
        }
        Logg.setText(log.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle Exception
    }
}
```

La programación es java de android, me muestra lo que esta sucediendo con la aplicación en tiempo real, pero me gustaría personalizarlo para que solo muestre los mensajes que yo le indique como por ejemplo:

```
  Log.i(TAG,"Falla en la Lectura");
```

Donde TAG es el nombre de mi aplicación y lo siguiente es el mensaje del proceso en curso.

De momento la función muestra todo lo que sucede y como muestra datos que no son importantes no me es posible ver en realidad lo que quiero.

Ideas!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo la imagen anterior es una captura de pantalla de la aplicación instalada y ejecutada en un SmartPhone 
Y lo único que quiero que muestre es por ejemplo el Mensaje
BufferRead : ????

Que son mensajes que configuró en algunas funciones y las uso para saber el valor de variables antes de que lleguen

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta ni por qué creaste tu propio método `Log` ¿?. Si quieres mostrar algo en algún punto sólo pones `Log.i(TAG,"Falla en la Lectura");` en el punto donde lo quieres mostrar. Aunque lo correcto sería: `Log.d(TAG,"Falla en la Lectura")` o bien `Log.d(TAG,"Falla en la Lectura")` Ten en cuenta que hay varios tipos de Log, la letra `i, d, e` sugiere que pongas de qué tipo sería tu Log, si de `i`nformación, si `d`ebug, si `e`rror, etc. Eso te sirve para escoger mostrar solamente ciertos tipos de Log. Si sólo quieres ver los Log de debug, de error, etc en Android Studio.

Comment: La función muestra el Log pero en tiempo real, es decir cuando se ejecuta en el dispositivo, veras, estoy transmitiendo bytes en formato Hexadecimal a un dispositivo y necesito ver las respuestas antes de que lleguen a mi función de lectura del Buffer de comunicación.

Comment: La función como esta ahorita muestra lo que sucede detrás de la aplicación caundo se ejecutan ciertos eventos como por ejemplo la conexión con un puerto muestra: intallation.packet.usbSerial = true

Comment: Y a lo que me refiero es que solo necesito ver los mensajes LOG que configuro en ciertos métodos para saber el valor de determinadas variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de poner el TAG con el nombre de la aplicación se suele poner el nombre de la clase que está ejecutando. En cada clase defines `public static final String TAG = MiClase.class.getSimpleName();`. Con esto luego en Android Studio podes filtrar por el nombre de la clase.

Y en tu programa:

```
protected void Log(){
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.contains("MiClase")) {
                log.append(line);
            }
        }
        Logg.setText(log.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle Exception
    }
}
```